# DirectX11 Mouse Control

Tags: c++, directx

I have a 3d program in DirectX and I want to give the mouse control to the camera. The problem is the mouse moves right off the screen ( In windowed mode ) then the camera doesn't turn anymore. I tried to use SetCusorPos to just lock it in place after the mouse is moved. That way I could get a dx and then set the mouse back to the center of the screen. I ended up getting a endless white screen. Here is my camera/mouse movement code so far. If you need any more information just ask.

```
void PhysicsApp::OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    // Make each pixel correspond to a quarter of a degree.
    float dx = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x));
    float dy = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y));

    // Update angles based on input to orbit camera around box.
    mTheta += -dx;
    mPhi   += -dy;
    // Update players direction to always face forward
    playerRotation.y = -mTheta;

    // Restrict the angle mPhi.
    mPhi = MathHelper::Clamp(mPhi, 0.1f, MathHelper::Pi-0.1f);

    if( (btnState & MK_RBUTTON) != 0 )
    {
        // Make each pixel correspond to 0.2 unit in the scene.
        float dx = 0.05f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x);
        float dy = 0.05f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y);

        // Update the camera radius based on input.
        mRadius += dx - dy;

        // Restrict the radius.
        mRadius = MathHelper::Clamp(mRadius, 5.0f, 50.0f);
    }
    mLastMousePos.x = x;
    mLastMousePos.y = y;
}
```

Comment: This code just makes some calculations and nothing more - what result do you expect? Anyway, according to your problem description, you need to capture the mouse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: It's a bad design to let your app window still receive the mouse message when the mouse out of your window.

Comment: When mouse enter in the area of your window, call [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to receive the mouse input, and when mouse leave the window, call ReleaseCapture to stop the mouse input.